# Python writing incorrect hex values

Tags: python, exploit

While attempting to write a hex value to ascii (\xdd\xba\x01\x10), I found that two of the values were being changed (\xdd\xba).

Instead of outputting Ýº or \xdd\xba\x01\x10
The output would be ݺ \x77a\x01\x10

I thought the issue might have been just how it was being assigned to the test var but using pack does the same.

```
test1 = "\xdd\xba\x01\x10" 
test2 = struct.pack("<I", 0x1001badd)
```

Both result in incorrect hex values being written.

I have temporarily fixed it by adding whitespace and cleaning it up when it writes to a file.

```
test1 = "\xdd \xba\x01\x10" 
cleanup = (test1)
file.write(cleanup.replace(" ", ""))
```

Python version is 2.7.2
OS is WINXP

and no I can't use Python3 or a newer version of Windows

Does anyone have any idea why this is occurring?

Comment: reverse the values, the program is reading 'd' as a unhexifying string you have to reverse the hex to fix this

Comment: Thanks. Opened it in Notepad++, changed the encoding and it was good.

Comment: im going to paste my answer as an answer so you can mark as closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reverse the values, the program is reading `d` as a unhexifying string you have to reverse the hex to fix this